# Paging in Gridview not working 2nd page data not showing data?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, paging

my gridview

```
<div style="margin-left: 280px">
   <asp:GridView ID="exportGrdVw" runat="server" BackColor="White"  
        AllowPaging="True" PageSize="3" 
        OnPageIndexChanging="exportGrdVw_PageIndexChanging" 
        onpageindexchanged="exportGrdVw_PageIndexChanged">
   </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

my code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=acer-Pc\\Sql;database=MYDB;trusted_connection=yes");  
//DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable table = new DataTable();    
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select customername,contactno,address from employee ", con);
        da.Fill(table);
        BindEmployee();
    }
 }
 public void BindEmployee()
 {
    exportGrdVw.DataSource = table;
    exportGrdVw.DataBind();
 }
 protected void exportGrdVw_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
 {
    exportGrdVw.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindEmployee();
 }
```

the problem is gridview is displaying but when i click page 2. 2nd page data is not showing (blank). pls help me to solve this problem.
see that the code is correct or not

Comment: What does your method "exportGrdVw_PageIndexChanged" look like?

Comment: In that method, you're going to have to get the data from your database again, then set the page index before you bind it.

Comment: tried this already still not working.

Comment: anyone else gridview dissapears after postback when page 2 clicked

Answer (score 13):

Use like below

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=acer-Pc\\Sql;database=MYDB;trusted_connection=yes");
//DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable table = new DataTable();    
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {              
       BindEmployee();
   }
}
public void BindEmployee()
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select customername,contactno,address from employee ", con);
    da.Fill(table);
    exportGrdVw.DataSource = table;
    exportGrdVw.DataBind();
}
protected void exportGrdVw_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    exportGrdVw.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindEmployee();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your datatable gets initialize in every page load so you need to get the datatable
everytime before binding it to grid.
Set your page Index before binding it to grid

So your code should be like this

```
public void BindEmployee(int newPageIndex = -1)
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select customername,contactno,address from employee ", con);
    da.Fill(table);
    exportGrdVw.PageIndex = newPageIndex;
    exportGrdVw.DataSource = table;
    exportGrdVw.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to call database on **exportGrdVw_PageIndexChanging**. Just declare DataTable table as **static**

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Emp_Data ORDER BY [ID] DESC", con);

SqlDataAdapter DA1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DA1.Fill(DT1);

GridView1.DataSource = DT1;
GridView1.DataBind();
```